# Visual Studio Android app not geting/post data to server

Tags: c#, android, database, visual-studio, xamarin

Im trying to learn some xamarin android app developing and i watch tutorial to connect my ms sql locar server with app using PHP file to post and get data from server but i got an error and i dont know why i got everything like in video and its not working its saying
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details." on this line of code

```
  void client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            string id = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result); //Get the data echo backed from PHP
            int newID = 0;

            int.TryParse(id, out newID); //Cast the id to an integer

            if (OnCreateContact != null)
            {
                //Broadcast event
                OnCreateContact.Invoke(this, new CreateContactEventArgs(newID, txtName.Text, txtNumber.Text));
            }

            mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            this.Dismiss();
        });
```

i trying some things but nothing works so far can u help me ? i add a link to project 
http://sendfile.es/pokaz/646790---epri.html

Or maybe its problem with my PHP file and place where i hold it. im using xampp which apatche got an PHP extansion for my ms sql server. im puting PHP file to
htdocs and this line of code

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/CreateContact.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("Name", txtName.Text);
        parameters.Add("Number", txtNumber.Text);

        client.UploadValuesCompleted += client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
```

Comment: Could you please include details on the inner exception?

Comment: This sort of thing usually means "something bad happened on the server that I don't know how to deal with" - and the InnerException will contain the detailed error message from the server.

Comment: Sorry its was so long but wasnt at home here is fille with debug output inner expections errors http://sendfile.es/pokaz/647587---gv9e.html